# 学校の宿題は回答するべきでしょうか

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲, 投票の仕方

学校の宿題や課題をそのまま質問に掲載した場合
個人的には回答するべきではないと思っています。
理由は誰にとってもプラスにならないからです。

みなさんどう考えますか？

そして、**親切にも** 宿題の答えつきの解説を 回答する人に対して
賛成票と 反対票 のどちらを入れるべきでしょうか。

参考: [[C言語][至急！木曜まで！]コマンド文字列検索をしたいです！アルゴリズムっぽいです！](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9370/c%E8%A8%80%E8%AA%9E%E8%87%B3%E6%80%A5-%E6%9C%A8%E6%9B%9C%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7-%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2%E3%82%92%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99-%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA%E3%82%BA%E3%83%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%BD%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99)

Comment: 「誰にとってもプラスにならない」のは何故でしょう？討議の出発点としては、何らかのアンカーが必要かと思いました。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 個人的には回答するべきではないと思っています。

各利用者の個人的な判断・態度については、ご自由にというところでしょうか。

> そして、親切にも 宿題の答えつきの解説を 回答する人に対して
>   賛成票と 反対票 のどちらを入れるべきでしょうか。

回答投稿に対する評価は **回答内容の質** に対してなされるべきであり、**対象質問の出自・内容・表現方法** に引きずられるのは好ましくありあません。あなたが、あなたの自由意志に基づいて反対投票を投ずるのを止められませんが、他者にも同じ判定基準を期待するのは適切でないと考えます。

なお対象投稿については、スタックオーバーフローの[質問ガイドライン](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)に照らして、単に「質の低い質問」であることには賛同します。

Comment: 「他者にも同じ判定基準を期待するのは適切でないと考えます」この点は全く同意です。わたしの個人的な判断はわたしが決めますので、それと同様に他者は他者の基準によって決めるべきです。わたしが質問したかったのは、わたしの個人的な基準（つまり反対票を入れる）がガイドラインに合うのだろうか？という点です。ガイドラインは無いということも理解しており、であればメタで聞いてみようと思い、投稿させていただきました。「 回答内容の質 に対してなされるべきであり、対象質問の出自・内容・表現方法 に引きずられるのは好ましくありあません」という内容が賛成票も多いようですので、その基準で賛成、反対を入れようと思います。ご意見どうもありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

宿題だからという理由で態度を変えたり制限を加えることには全く賛同できません。
take88さんは主張が一般化できないか再検討してみて下さい。

たとえばスタック・オーバーフローでは明らかに職業上の質問であるものも一定数見受けられますが、それらは宿題と比べて法的・倫理的にクリアと言えますか？
学習効果を理由にされるかもしれませんが、学生でなければカンニングしても良いのでしょうか？

はっきり言うと無意識に年少者を抑圧しようという発想の提案に見えます。

Comment: わたしは何ら主張してません。反対を入れるべきか、賛成を入れるべきか、と言った質問です。「はっきり言うと無意識に年少者を抑圧しようという発想の提案に見えます。」というご意見は、わたしの書き方の問題でそのような印象を持たれたのかもしれませんね。ご意見どうもありがとうございました。