# 生成系AIを利用した投稿をどのように扱うべきでしょうか？

Tags: 討議, chatgpt

2022年以降、GPTやStable Diffusionなどコンテンツを生成する大規模生成モデルの一般利用が広がりました。特にChatGPTが生成した文章は、一見すると非常に理知的で、説得力があるように見えることがあり、多くの有益な用途が考えられます。

他方でこうした進歩に伴い、Stack Exchangeのいくつかのサイトでは弊害も出てきています。そのひとつが、AIが生成した低品質なコンテンツの氾濫です。既にいくつかのサイトでは利用を制限する動きも出てきており、Stack OverflowはChatGPTの利用を禁止しています<sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)</sup>。さらに他のQ&Aサイトへ目を向けると、teratailはAIが生成した質問の投稿を禁止し、AIが生成した回答については生成したモデルを明記することで可能としています<sup>[[2]](https://teratail.com/help#about-ai-terms)</sup>。

このような他サイトの状況を鑑みても、スタック・オーバーフローにおける生成系AIの利用に関して議論する意義はあると思います。そこで質問です。スタック・オーバーフローでは、生成系AIを利用した投稿をどのように扱うべきでしょうか？

> #### Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable - Stack Overflow<sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)</sup>
>
> （前略）
> The objective nature of the content on Stack Overflow means that if any part of an answer is wrong, then the answer is objectively wrong. In order for Stack Overflow to maintain a strong standard as a reliable source for correct and verified information, such answers must be edited or replaced. However, because GPT is good enough to convince users of the site that the answer holds merit, signals the community typically use to determine the legitimacy of their peers’ contributions frequently fail to detect severe issues with GPT-generated answers. As a result, information that is objectively wrong makes its way onto the site. In its current state, GPT risks breaking readers’ trust that our site provides answers written by subject-matter experts.
>
> Moderators are empowered (at their discretion) to issue immediate suspensions of up to 30 days to users who are copying and pasting GPT content onto the site, with or without prior notice or warning.

> #### AIが生成した文章について投稿したい - teratail<sup>[[2]](https://teratail.com/help#about-ai-terms)</sup>
>
> AIが生成した文章を投稿する場合は、以下の条件に従ってください。
>
> ##### AIが生成した質問について
>
> - AIが生成した質問の投稿は禁止しております。
> - AIが生成した質問と判断された場合は、運営チームで削除させていただく場合がございます。
>
> ##### AIが生成した回答・コメントについて
>
> - AIが生成した回答・コメントを投稿する場合は、1行目に「[アルゴリズム/サービス名]により生成された文章です」と明記する必要があります。明記されていない場合は運営チームで削除させていただく場合がございます。
> - 投稿する場合は、内容が正しいかを精査してください。

Comment: どうすべきかというか、実際に問題があるのかどうかで判断すべきと思っています。現状困っていることや嬉しいことがあるのであればその事実ベースで判断したいですし、特に何も起こっていない上に将来的にも大きな影響があるか分からないのであれば今急いで何かを判断する必要は無いかな、と。

Comment: Stack Overflow の方はリンク先が消えていて、代わりに ChatGPT に限定せず [AI 生成ツール全般を指すような内容のページが出来ています](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy) 。(引用部分が精査できていないので、こちらの投稿はそのままにしておきます)

Answer (score 2):

「AIが生成した質問/回答」と書かれると、それらを無加工(あるいはわずかな語句修正程度)でそのまま投稿されるイメージですが、実際には「AIに質問して得られた回答が理解できない(プログラムが動かない)」という質問や、「質問についてAIに聞いた答えからこう解決しました(あるいはこれが原因では？)」みたいな回答が増えることが考えられます。

例えば現時点で日本語版StackOverflowをChatGPTで検索すると18件出てきますね。
['chatgpt'を含む新着の投稿](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=ChatGPT&searchOn=3)
(スクリーンショットでは無いのでリンク先を見た時点での情報で件数は変わります)

キーワードでの検索なのでそれらがこの記事に該当するものばかりでは無いでしょうが、現時点での既に発生している事例がどんなものかを参考に見てみるのも良いのではないでしょうか？

---

ある程度はこちらの記事と似たような議論になりそうです。
[学校の宿題は回答するべきでしょうか](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1805/26370)

今のところはAIが生成したとしても他と同様に内容により以下対処すれば良いと思われます。
[気持ちよく参加するために](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)
[質問が [クローズ済み] とは？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

Answer (score 1):

生成系AIを利用した投稿は抑制するどころか、(権利や規約を守って)制限なく積極的に活用して良いと思います。
ただし投稿者が生成系AIの回答を十分に**理解**し、慎重に**検証**した上で、**行動規範**を守って投稿するならば。

太字の意図を簡単に弁明します。

- **理解**
  一見説得力のある回答を瞬時に生成し、投稿者が理解しないまま断定口調で容易に投稿できてしまうことこそ、生成系AI制限が槍玉に上がる要因だと認識しています。
  生成系AIのコピペ投稿は機械翻訳のコピペ投稿と酷似した問題を抱えています。
  どちらも意味が通っているように見えて全体的にいびつで不気味かつノイジーな文章になりがちです。
- **検証**
  投稿者が理解できない文章の確からしさを本人が検証できる訳もありません。
  すなわち理解を放棄した投稿は、検証を読者に丸投げしながら質問や修正依頼に対処できないことが問題です。
  しかも多くのAIは出典を示さないまま自信満々に間違える点も厄介です。
- [**行動規範**](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)
  質問者のプログラミングに関連する悩みを回答者が円満解決してナレッジベース化する役割に徹することができるならば、その主体が人でも機械でも外なる神でも私は構いません。
  しかし現時点でAIが主体となるには理解と検証と送信ボタンを押す指の数が足りていません。
  投稿する人間がNiceに使いこなさなければ行動規範のリンク先にある「誤解を招く情報」が増え、「ツールの乱用」や「不正使用」の問題につながります。

結論として、生成系AIの利用で発生する問題のほぼすべては主体となるユーザの問題に帰着します。
そして残念ながら制限や禁止してもやる人はやるのです。時には利用の事実を隠しながら。

なので制限や禁止事項を作るよりもむしろ文章校正などの補助的な利用を促すのはどうでしょうか。
生成系AIの活用例やFAQをメタやヘルプで紹介して、適切に利用できる環境を整える方が建設的で質の高いコミュニティにつながると信じています。

その結果AIの回答を丸ごとコピペした(ように見える)質の低い投稿が出たときは、通常の投稿と同様に編集やクローズ票、コメント等で改善を促せるはずです。
もしそれを繰り返すユーザがいれば、それはAIではなくユーザの問題となるでしょう。

---

実はこの回答を書いては消しを繰り返しています。
何が投稿をためらわせているのか言語化しにくいのですが、どうやら私は「生成系AIの**利用**ってどこまで？」という線引きに答えが出せないのでモヤッとしているようです。

完全コピペはNGだとしましょう。
てはプロンプトを書き換えてパラメータを調整しながら何万回も試行錯誤した結果、非の打ち所がない回答になってもNGですか？

数文字改変しただけではNGですか。
n文字改変でNGな時、n+1文字改変してもやっぱりNGですか？
むしろ英語で出力して翻訳すれば全文改変したのでOKですか？

ひどく尖った例えで申し訳ありませんが、AI制限論にはどうにも「なぜAIを制限するのか」がついてこない、**制限のための制限**が見受けられるように感じてしまうのです。

生成系AI制限派の中にも「そこまでの制限は望まない」方がいるかもしれません。
しかし利用をどこまで制限して何を禁止するか明示できないならば、真面目で良識的な利用者ほど委縮して投稿をためらい、不真面目で独善的な利用者は特記事項を拡大解釈してほぼコピペを繰り返す事態が起こり得ます。

他に思い付く事態として「この投稿は100%人間なのか」と悪魔の証明を迫るコメント合戦となれば、これほど不毛なチューリングテストはないでしょう。

最後に、スタック・オーバーフローはNiceなユーザが多く秩序が守られているので、今すぐ制限/禁止事項を増やさなくても運用はうまく回ると半ば確信しています。
精力的にサイトの運用を考えてくださっているモデレータの皆様にも深く感謝しています。

どうかこの非常にNiceなサイトに不便なルールが増えて誰も望まぬ結果とならないことを願っています。