# AI によって生成された文章を使った投稿に関するポリシーについて、ヘルプセンターに新しく記事が作られる予定です

Tags: 討議, chatgpt

日本語版スタック・オーバーフローでは 2024 年 2 月上旬現在、LLM を始めとする AI を使って生成された文章を利用した投稿について、サイト独自のポリシーは特に設けておりません。 [生成系AIを利用した投稿をどのように扱うべきでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3887/19110) にて議論が進んでいますが、まだ合意には至っていない認識です。

一方、Stack Exchange ネットワーク全体に対するルールについては Meta Stack Exchange で議論が進んでいます。複数の投稿に分かれて議論されており、そのいくつかは長い議論になっているので自分も全ては追えていないのですが、たとえば [Is uncited LLM usage considered a CoC violation under the Inauthentic Usage policy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393679/341401) では「AI の生成結果をそのままコピー＆ペーストしたものを AI を使ったと書かずに投稿するのは、Code of Conduct の [Inauthentic usage policy](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct/inauthentic-usage) に違反している」という結論になっています。

こういった議論の中で、 [Proposed changes to Help Center articles to include mention of AI-generated content policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396626/341401) で告知されたところによると、ヘルプセンターに以下の変更が予定されています。

- /help/ai-policy に新しくページが作られ、上に書いたようなポリシーがより具体的に説明されるようになります。
- [/help/referencing](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) の内容が少し変わり、/help/ai-policy への参照が書き足されます。

これらの変更は 2024 年 2 月 14 日に行われることが予定されています。

ネットワーク全体に対する変更ですので、記事自体についてもし何かご意見がある場合は [Proposed changes to Help Center articles to include mention of AI-generated content policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396626/341401) までご投稿お願いいたします。

また、この記事の翻訳については追って別のメタ投稿を使って行えるはずだと考えています。ヘルプページなのでおそらく https://ja.traducir.win/ の string としては管理されず、個別に和訳することになりそうです。なお翻訳はあくまで翻訳ですので、翻訳プロセスの中では意味を変えるような書き換えは行わないつもりです。

もし何かこのサイトでの AI 利用のされ方について変えたいことがあれば、都度メタに投稿いただければと思います。以上、来週あたりに予定されている変更のお知らせでした。